# reverse hex number into a string

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I want to convert unsigned long long

```
0xabcd1234
```

to this string

```
3412cdab
```

*we want to keep leading zeroes so for example 0x1 will convert to this string "01000000" and 0x123 to "23010000"

now I succeded in writing code that does that but I wonder if there is a much simpler way

```
char* encode_long_long_hex(unsigned long long integer, char* out, 
                           int  len, size_t *out_len)
{
    static char encode_hex_char_arr[] = {
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',  
        '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'
    };

    char* dst = out;
    unsigned idx = count_long_long_digits(integer); //return number of digits
    
    while (idx && dst < out + len)
    {
        idx -= 2;
        
        *dst = encode_hex_char_arr[(integer & 0xF0) >> 4];
        dst += sizeof(char);
        
        *dst = encode_hex_char_arr[integer & 0x0F];
        dst += sizeof(char);
        
        integer >>= 8;
    }

    *out_len = (int) (dst - out);
    
    return dst;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: what about `0x12345`.  What is the expected output?

Comment: <humor>`char *string="3412cdab";`. Much simpler</humor> More seriously, why not `printf(string, "%02X%02X%02X%02X", lValue&0xFF, lValue>>8&0xFF, lValue>>16&0xFF, lValue>>24&0xFF);` ? (but take care of the endianess of your ints)

Comment: @Zilog80 In fact endianness does not matter here, the code you posted (which aligns with my answer) is endianness-agnostic.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You're right, sorry i missed your answer (I point Endianess for the origin of the long long value <== Where OP get the value, not for what the C compiler will do with a long long, but yes that could be misunderstood, and out of scope) ^^.Just for the point, Op asked for unsigned long long reverse, you should also add a zero trim ^^

Comment: @ 0___________ it 0x12345 --->. 45230100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the formal question you are asking is "how do I convert an int represented as hex from big-endian to little-endian" (or vice-versa)

If so then the formal answer would be "parse the hex, convert the endianess, format back to hex", or in other words `format(convert(parse(input)))`, or in C:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <byteswap.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char output[11];
sprintf(output, "0x%x", bswap_32(strtol(input, NULL, 0)));

// Or without "0x" in both input and output:

char output[9];
sprintf(output, "%x", bswap_32(strtol(input, NULL, 16)));
```

Comment: Nice catch. I was looking for __builtin_bswap64, but it's GCC builtin. htobe64 maybe, but not very portable. Isn't bswap_32 linux only ?

Comment: `strtoull()` makes more sense than `strtol()` to achieve " want to convert unsigned long long".

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler way utilizing `sprintf` to do the conversion from number to characters for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned x = 0xabcd1234;
    char s[40];
    sprintf(s, "%02x%02x%02x%02x", 
        x & 0xFF,
        (x >> 8) & 0xFF,
        (x >> 16) & 0xFF,
        (x >> 24) & 0xFF
    );
    
    printf("%s\n", s);
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

This will "feed" the original number byte-wise to `sprintf` which will format these as hexadecimals. (Note, I used `unsigned` type here, not `long long`, because the number in your example fitting it *on my platform*. If you need larger types, you can adapt this method too).

[Demo](https://ideone.com/OoFoyy)

Comment: for `long long` it will not be simpler - tons of parameters

Comment: @0___________ Longer, yes, but I still think simpler - no logic whatsoever involved - just mechanical work :)

Comment: He wants to convert `unsigned long long` `0xabcd1234` to `"3412cdab"` not to `"3412cdab00000000"`  as in your code if we extend it to unsigned long long. Simply wrong solution. Imagine he want to convert `0x12` even in your example : https://godbolt.org/z/Pa18b95E5

Comment: I meant `0x1234`

Comment: @0___________ You might be right on this, the op might want to clarify though

Comment: He was quete clear. In his code he uses unsigned long long and the converted form is without zeroes. What to clarify?

Comment: for example 0x00001234 ---> 34120000

Comment: So you do want to keep the zeros?

Comment: actually in this case 0x00001234 ---> 34120000  it doesn't matter
of course 0x12340000 ---> 00003412 is matter

Comment: Thus, truncate leading zeros of the results ?

Comment: Meaning the desired result for 0x1234 would be `34120000` or  `3412`? Also for `0x123` - should it be `231` 0r `0231` or `02310000` ?

Comment: let's say we will save the leading zeroes for simplicity
so 1234 --> 34120000
123 --> 23010000

Comment: Well, then the answer should do. Perhaps you might want to update the question

Comment: I'll add this note

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void toHexReverse(unsigned long long val, char *buff)
{
    static const char hex[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    while(val)
    {
        buff[1] = hex[val % 16];
        val /= 16;
        buff[0] = hex[val % 16];
        val /= 16;
        buff += 2;
    }
    *buff = 0;
}


int main(void)
{
    char buff[20];
    toHexReverse(0xabcd1234, buff);
    printf("%s\n", buff);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/37zvM75MK